# Pandas DataFrame fields convert as key and values in python

Tags: python, pandas

```
Date            sector  weight
0  2011-01-10      a      12
1  2011-01-10      b      23
2  2011-01-11      c      34
3  2011-01-11      d      54
```

- My DF like this i want this result in the following format

  {2011-01-10:{a:12, b:23}, 2011-01-11:{c:34, d:54}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) + [`to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_json.html):

```
#if necessary convert to string
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str)
df = df.groupby('Date').apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['sector'], x['weight']))).to_json()
print (df)
{"2011-01-10":{"b":23,"a":12},"2011-01-11":{"c":34,"d":54}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grpby = df.set_index(['Date', 'sector']).weight.groupby('Date')
{n: g.xs(n).to_dict() for n, g in grpby}

{'2011-01-10': {'a': 12, 'b': 23}, '2011-01-11': {'c': 34, 'd': 54}}
```